# Python & PDFs: Filling out and flattening form fields including image field (pypdf)

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, reportlab

I'm looking for a way that I can create a pdf template in Adobe with form fields where I can add text and an image to the template fields.

I've tried using pypdf and I can add text to the text form fields, but I can't find a way to add an image to the image form field. I also can't flatten the pdf using pypdf (so I can't see the fields, just the text), my attempted code is below but it's deleting the fields. Is this possible using pypdf?

Is this possible using another library?

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from pprint import pprint
import pypdf

reader = PdfReader("input_form.pdf")
fields = reader.get_fields()
pprint(fields)

writer = PdfWriter()
page = reader.pages[0]
writer.append(reader)

writer.update_page_form_field_values(
    writer.pages[0], {
        "Text1": "some filled in text"
    }
)

with open("filled-out.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)


def flatten_pdf(input_pdf, output_pdf):
    with open(input_pdf, "rb") as infile:
        reader = pypdf.PdfReader(infile)
        writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()

        for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
            page = reader.pages[page_num]
            if page.get('/Annots'):
                del page['/Annots']
            writer.add_page(page)

        with open(output_pdf, "wb") as outfile:
            writer.write(outfile)

flatten_pdf("filled-out.pdf", "filled-out.pdf")
```